# Tomcat pool DataSource not found on tomcat 7.0.26

Tags: jdbc, tomcat7, connection-pooling

When I try to deploy a webapp in tomcat 7.0.26 I get the following exception:
ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource

But as far as I have read, this class was introduced on tomcat 7.0.19.

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you install Tomcat? Is tomcat-jdbc.jar present in $CATALINA_HOME/lib ?

Comment: I'm sorry, that was probable the answer to the problem. But I solved it by manually installing a newer version (7.0.42). The other version (7.0.26) was installed from ubuntu repo...